# How do you fetch a list of records and then add a checkbox next to corresponding record so to edit and save changes in suiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to create a suitelet that could fetch some sales order then be able to edit those on click on submit button, so far I was I'm able to fetch records but I'm not able to add checkboxes and update records in netsuite - suitescript

```
            var list=form.createList({title:"Sales order"});
            list.addColumn({
            id : 'column1',
            type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            label : 'tranid',
            align : serverWidget.LayoutJustification.LEFT
            });list.addColumn({
            id : 'column2',
            type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            label : 'shipaddress',
            align : serverWidget.LayoutJustification.LEFT
            });list.addColumn({
            id : 'column3',
            type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            label : 'rate',
            align : serverWidget.LayoutJustification.LEFT
            });
             
            salesorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
    
                tranid= result.getValue({name: 'tranid'})
        
                shipaddress= result.getValue({name: 'shipaddress'})
        
                rate= result.getValue({name: 'rate'})
            


    



                list.addRows({
                rows : [{
                column1 : tranid,
                column2 : shipaddress,
                column3 : rate


                }]
                });
```

Comment: For clarity, are you wanting to display a page of Transaction saved search results and allow users (via checkbox) to indicate which Transactions to have updated?  Then upon the user submitting the form, the system would know which Transactions to update and which not to update?  Perhaps displaying back to the user which were and were not updated?

Comment: Yes exactly, I only want to update the selected records. I dont want any output back. just on clicking the submit button they should be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suite Answer Id [40768](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/40768/kw/40768) has sample code in SuiteScript 1.0.  An outline in 2.0 format is below.  The full 1.0 sample from NetSuite is also below.  The key is to for the GET req method create the page and display the information as a Sublist instead of a List.  Then for all other req methods, get the parameters and take desired action.

2.0 partial outline

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'], function(serverWidget) {
  function onRequest(context){
    if(context.request.method === 'GET'){
      //create page to display results and allow for user input
      var form = serverWidget.createForm({
        title : 'Simple Form'
      });
      var sublist = form.addSublist({
        id : 'sublistid',
        type : serverWidget.SublistType.INLINEEDITOR,
        label : 'Inline Editor Sublist'
      });
      //Add checkbox and atleast internalid
      var printField = sublist.addField({
        id: 'custpage_rec_process',
        label: 'Process',
        type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX
      });
      var idField = sublist.addField({
        id: 'custpage_rec_id',
        label: 'Internal ID',
        type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
      });

      //empty Array to hold Sales Order data
      var TranIds = [];
      //run search to get Sales Order data
      ...salesorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
        //add search column names as columns in the sublist
        
        //add each column value to the sublist
      }
      
      //add buttons to sublist and form
      sublist.addMarkAllButtons();
      sublist.addRefreshButton();
      form.addResetButton({label: 'Reset'});
      form.addSubmitButton({label: 'Create File'});

      //display page for user input
      context.response.writePage(form);
      
    } else { //if the previously created/displayed form has been submitted display the following to the user
      var req = context.request;
      var params = JSON.stringify(context.request.parameters);//can log this to see exactly how the information comes through
      //gather submitted data

      //take desired action
      
      //display response to user
      context.response.writePage('Done');
    }
  } return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  }
});
```

1.0 full sample

```
function suitelet(request, response){
 
 //Create the form that will be used by the POST and GET requests
 var form = nlapiCreateForm('Delete Transactions');
 
 //GET - Show a list of transactions from the search results so the user can select the ones to be deleted
 if (request.getMethod() == 'GET' )
 {
  // Run an existing transaction search
  var results = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', 'customsearch_mass_deletion_results');
 
  // Create a sublist to show the search results
  var sublist = form.addSubList('custpage_transaction_list', 'list','Transactions');
 
  // Create an array to store the transactions from the search results
  var transactionArray = new Array();
 
  if (results!=null)
  {
   // Add a checkbox column to the sublist to select the transactions that will be deleted.
   sublist.addField('delete','checkbox', 'Delete');
 
   // Add hidden columns for the Internal ID and for the Record type.
   // These fields are necessary for the nlapiDeleteRecord function.
   sublist.addField('internalid','text', 'Internal ID').setDisplayType('hidden');
   sublist.addField('recordtype','text', 'Record Type').setDisplayType('hidden');
 
   // Add a column for the Internal ID link
   sublist.addField('internalidlink','text', 'Internal ID');
 
   // Get the the search result columns
   var columns = results[0].getAllColumns();
 
   // Add the search columns to the sublist
   for(var i=0; i< columns.length; i++)
   {
    sublist.addField(columns[i].getName() ,'text', columns[i].getName() );
   }
 
   // For each search results row, create a transaction object and attach it to the transactionArray
   for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++)
   {
    var transaction = new Object();
 
    // Set the Delete column to False
    transaction['delete'] = 'F';
    // Set the hidden internal ID field
    transaction['internalid'] = results[i].getId();
    // Set the hidden record type field
    transaction['recordtype'] = results[i].getRecordType();
 
    // Create a link so users can navigate from the list of transactions to a specific transaction
    var url = nlapiResolveURL('RECORD', results[i].getRecordType() ,results[i].getId(), null);
    internalIdLink = " " + results[i].getId() +" ";
 
    // Set the link
    transaction['internalidlink'] = internalIdLink;
 
    // Copy the row values to the transaction object
    for(var j=0; j< columns.length ; j++)
    {
     transaction[columns[j].getName()] = results[i].getValue(columns[j].getName());
    }
 
    // Attach the transaction object to the transaction array
    transactionArray[i] = transaction;
   }
  }
 
  // Initiate the sublist with the transactionArray
  sublist.setLineItemValues(transactionArray);

  sublist.addMarkAllButtons();
  form.addSubmitButton('Submit' );

  response.writePage( form );
 }
 //POST - Delete the selected transactions and show a confirmation message
 else
 {
  // Check how many lines in the sublist
  var count = request.getLineItemCount('custpage_transaction_list');
 
  // This variable will keep track of how many records are deleted.
  var num = 0;
 
  //for each line in the sublist
  for(var i=1; i< count+1; i++)
  {
   //get the value of the Delete checkbox
   var deleteTransaction = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'delete', i);
 
   // If it's checked, delete the transaction
   if(deleteTransaction == 'T')
   {
    // Get the transaction internal ID
    var internalId = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'internalid', i);
    // Get the transaction type
    var recordType = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'recordtype', i);
    try
    {
     // Delete the transaction
     nlapiDeleteRecord(recordType, internalId);
     num++;
    }
    // Errors will be logged in the Execution Log
    catch(ex)
    {
     nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Error', 'Transaction ID '+ internalId +': '+ ex);
    }
   }
 
  }
  // Show how many records were deleted.
  form.addField("custpage_transaction_total", "text").setDisplayType('inline').setDefaultValue(num + " transactions deleted");
 
  response.writePage( form );
 }
}
```